# swedish characters check with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I rewrite this code to check for all characters including the swedish å, ä, and ö characters?

```
      alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

The above only checks against english letters!

The swedish contains å, ä, ö coming after the Z... rest is all the same as english.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much [straight from the horse's mouth](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/712206-regex-accents#post2832674):

> Support for
>   internationalization in JavaScript's RegExp is virtually nonexistent.

See the posts following the linked one for how to get around this (by defining your own character class).

Comment: This is no longer the case. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html . However no \p{Swedish} exists. I suggest we define \p{Swedish} including diacritics and foreign characters. This can be used for Latin-1 /^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u00FF]+$/ .

Answer (score 13):

Did you try `/^[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]+$/`?

In my Firefox, `/^[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]+$/.test("öÅ");` evaluates to true.

Comment: What about diacritics and foreign characters, like é and ü? What is the full set of characters to allow?

Comment: @DavidJonsson That will depend on what you're trying to validate. The poster asked about adding 'äöå' to 'a-z'. If you want to allow an arbitrary text, you'll obviously need to allow for more.

Comment: No, the poster didn't just ask about åäö, but all Swedish characters, and that includes diacritics and foreign chracters.

Answer (score 2):

You have PHP and JavaScript marked in here.  For the JavaScript answer, see the previous answer from Matt Ball.

For the PHP answer, see `\p` and friends.  `\p{L}` for example.

```
php -r '$foo = "täst"; if ( preg_match("/^\\p{L}+$/",$foo) ) echo "yay\n";'
```

Comment: Since the link to documentation is missing: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php