# Regular expression not working for at least one European character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am checking whether my string contains at least one character of a European language(Example: German, Spanish,English etc...)

I tried like the following:

```
var check = "abc";

if(check.match(/^[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]+$/)){
               alert("if");
               }
   else{
   alert("else");
   }
```

It should only work if it is having at least a European language character. Should not work if numbers only. Please guide me guys!!

Comment: The `/^` part means that only the first characters of the string will be matched. Also, if you only want to find out if there is *one* EU character then you do not need the `+`. Something like `check.test(/[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]/)` would do the job.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to remove the anchors and the quantifier and use `test`:

```js
alert(/(?![×÷])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]/.test("ß1111"))
alert(/(?![×÷])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]/.test("ö"))
alert(/(?![×÷])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]/.test("12345"))
```

The `(?![×÷])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]` regex is an adaptation of the regex provided in [Useful ASCII Ranges](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html). It will capture all Latin and accented characters.

***Some more [language-related character ranges](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#languages) you can use***:

**French** Letters: `[a-zA-ZàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒ]`

**German** Letters: `[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]`

**Polish** Letters only: `[a-pr-uwy-zA-PR-UWY-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]` (**Note** that there is no `Q`, `V` and `X` in Polish, but if you want to allow all English letters as well, use `[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]`)

**Italian** Letters: `[a-zA-ZàèéìíîòóùúÀÈÉÌÍÎÒÓÙÚ]`

**Spanish** Letters: `[a-zA-ZáéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ]`

*And some more...*

**Swedish**: `[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669503/3832970))

**Norwegian**: `[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]` ([link](http://www.fiskeklubben.org/charcters/digitized.html))

**Danish** (same as Norwegian): `[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_and_Norwegian_alphabet))

**Greek & Coptic + Greek Extended**: `[\u0370-\u03FF\u1F00-\u1FFF]` ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet))

**Russian**: `[а-яА-ЯёЁ]` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet))

**Ukrainian**: `[а-щА-ЩЬьЮюЯяЇїІіЄєҐґ]` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet))

**Serbian (Cyrillic)**: `[А-ИК-ШЂЈ-ЋЏа-ик-шђј-ћџ]` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbian_Cyrillic_alphabet))

**Bulgarian** (subset of Russian alphabet): `[а-ъьюяА-ЪЬЮЯ]` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_alphabet))

**Belarusian** script range: `[ёа-зй-шы-яЁА-ЗЙ-ШЫІіЎў]` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_alphabet))

**Romanian**: `[a-zA-ZĂÂÎȘȚăâîșț]` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet))

Comment: @AvinashRaj: What is the problem with `console.log`?

Comment: no need for using the snippet if you use `console.log`

Comment: @stribizhev I found an error in German characters. It is not working. Please take a look.alert(/[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]/.test("ßßßß")). Returns false. Help me buddy :(

Comment: Ok, I see that you are looking for all the characters that are used in European languages. It is not a trivial task. You can check the [Regular Expression: Match Unicode Block Range](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) to build the range you need selecting only those scripts you are going to check.

Comment: I checked that but that list does not have Swedish and German characters. Please Help me if you can build that expression for me??

Comment: Got it buddy /[a-zA Z\x7f- \xff]/ it worked for me. I tried it!! Thank you so much for your precious time!!

Comment: I do not think it is correct, since `1111§` will be considered "true". Or is it OK?

Comment: §. I do not have any idea about this symbol buddy. Can you suggest me from which language it is from??

Comment: It is not a letter, it is a paragraph symbol. You need to build the regex by adding the ranges that are pertinent to the languages you want to cover with your regex. Here is [Swedish](https://www.iana.org/domains/idn-tables/tables/se_sv-se_1.0.html). Perhaps, this one - [`(?:(?![×Þß÷þø])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ])`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html) - will work for you.

Comment: At the risk of being called "buddy": the "Useful ASCII Ranges" regex is wrong (in a sense). The characters `Þ` `ß` `þ` and `ø` are also 'regular' letters in various languages. It's only wrong "in a sense" because it is called "All Latin and Accented Characters"; but that does not expand to "[all] character[s] of a European language".

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, I get your point. I am adding more script ranges now.

Comment: @Santhucool: You can get the [list of European languages](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/european_languages.htm) and check them on the Web by searching "*language* alphabet". I am not sure which languages you want to cover.

Comment: @stribizhev: Actually, Ukrainian considers apostrophe (`'`) a letter, not punctuation mark, so you should perhaps include it, too.