# Translating RegEx from PHP to Asp.Net RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: php, asp.net, regex

I currently have this RegularExpressionValidator running:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev_Nachname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="edtNachname"
                            Display="None" ErrorMessage="$InvalidBeginOfStringNonTechnik$Nachname$2" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-ZÆÄÜÖáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüß0-9'-]{2}.*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I do have the requirement now to change it to Unicode - Latin and created following RegEx for PHP:

```
^[\p{Latin}+\p{M}*+0-9'-]{2,}
```

After changing regex and deploying the site in question - the application will just run into a timeout if I open the site where I changed the Regex - If I undo my changes everythings fine.

Since I do not recieve any errors I am kinda in the dark - but thinking that ASP cannot handle my RegEx.
Is there anything obvious why it isn't working?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is the regex working on server side only? What exact Unicode ranges and  characters you need to match? Your `^[\p{Latin}+\p{M}*+0-9'-]{2,}` regex matches two or more chars, latin, plus, diacritic, asterisk, digits, apostrophe or a hyphen.

Comment: I need to match every letter which is listed here: http://xoev.de/latinchars/1_1/latinchars.pdf
as well as 0-9,',-

That \p{M}*+ is taken from here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html
Part: Unicode Categories

It seems like the Regexvalidator doesn't like the \p{Latin}

Comment: What is the range of the Basic Latin? Is it just all printable ASCII? Try `[ -~]` to match any ASCII char. Again, is the regex executed on the server or client or both? The point is that `\p` and `*+` are not supported by the regex engine.

Comment: Regex is validated both, server and client.
Range is basically every .NET Subset of LatinScripts available listed here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks

But any non letters in those ranges need to be restricted

ASCII ASCII was implemented previously, we need to match now every LatinChar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to allow all Unicode categories that have *Latin* in their names. Here are their ranges:

```
| Code point range  |        Block name            |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|   0000 - 007F     |    IsBasicLatin              |
|   0080 - 00FF     |    IsLatin-1Supplement       |
|   0100 - 017F     |    IsLatinExtended-A         | 
|   0180 - 024F     |    IsLatinExtended-B         |
|   1E00 - 1EFF     |    IsLatinExtendedAdditional |
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

So, you can create a custom special class from them and add `'0-9-` to it to get your extended version of your previous regex: `[\u0000-\u007F\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-024F\u1E00-\u1EFF'0-9-]`.

However, your current regex only matches the start of string `^`, exactly 2 chars from your custom character class (the `[...]{2}` part), and then any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols (`.*`). The extended version will look like

```
^[\u0000-\u007F\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-024F\u1E00-\u1EFF'0-9-]{2}.*
```

If you need to allow two or more symbols from your custom character class, use

```
^[\u0000-\u007F\u0080-\u00FF\u0100-\u017F\u0180-024F\u1E00-\u1EFF'0-9-]{2,}$
```

**UPDATE**:

So, it turns out you need to support diacritics from outside the BMP plane, and specific Unicode code point ranges excluding some of them.

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?![\u0009-\u002F\u003A-\u0040])[a-zA-Z\u006E-\u0302\u006D-\u0302\u004A-\u030C'0-9-])|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])){2,}
```

And here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6qTrNY/1)

The main part of the pattern is `(?:(?![\u0009-\u002F\u003A-\u0040])[a-zA-Z\u006E-\u0302\u006D-\u0302\u004A-\u030C'0-9-])`, and the rest is for matching diacritics.

Comment: They will be able to use symbols like the € one with that regex - I want to deny that, that's why I didn't want to use the regex you posted with the ranges!

Is there any way to prevent that without excluding EACH NonLetter available in these ranges?

Will Characters with two CodePoints be matched? E.g. 0044+0302

Comment: In JS, you cannot eaily match code points outside of  the BMP plane in ES5. In ES6, that is easier, but not sure the browsers will support that. Note you have not actually stated what *letters* you need, but I suspect you want `(?![×÷])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/3832970. It would be best if you could supply some valid and invalid inputs for me to test.

Comment: These shall not be matched:
0009-002F
003A-0040

These shall be matched:
006E+0302
006D+0302
004A+030C

Comment: Something like [`^(?:(?![\u0009-\u002F\u003A-\u0040])[\u006E-\u0302\u006D-\u0302\u004A-\u030C'0-9-]){2}.*`](https://regex101.com/r/cP8NgU/1)?

Comment: D̂ (0044+0302) won't get matched by that.
So I need to add those manually?
That'll be tiresome.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps, that will work - https://regex101.com/r/6qTrNY/1

Comment: That seems to cover everything!
Thanks :)