# Python - Regex cyrillic mixed with latin

Tags: python, regex, cyrillic

I'm trying to extract the cyrillic letters from a mixed input but can't get it to split the way I want. No numbers or special characters involved.

```
input = "я я я я я w w w w w w\nф ф ф ф ф v v v v v v"
output = re.split("![а-я]\s*", input)
print(output)
```

I want to get rid of the `w` and `v` letters and just print the Russian ones. With my code, input and output are the same except that they're in a list now.

Comment: Russian or Cyrillic? Try `output = re.findall(r'(?i)[А-ЯЁ]', input)` if you only need Russian letters in  a list. What is the exact expected output? BTW, is it Python 3?

Comment: thank you, this resolved my problem! EDIT: sorry I needed to match both Russian and Ukrainian. It's mixed input. Can I still use this?

Comment: For Ukranian, you need to update it. Do you want to treat `'` as a letter, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get all the Russian letters from your string, you need to use `(?i)[А-ЯЁ]` regex (do not forget about `Ё` as `[А-Я]` range does not include it) and use it with `re.findall`.

Tested in Python 3:

```
>>> import re
>>> input = "я я я я я w w w w w w\nф ф ф ф ф v v v v v v"
>>> output = re.findall(r'(?i)[А-ЯЁ]', input)
>>> print(output)
['я', 'я', 'я', 'я', 'я', 'ф', 'ф', 'ф', 'ф', 'ф']
```

To also extract Ukranian letters, you need to add `ЇІЄҐ` to the character class:

```
 output = re.findall(r"(?i)[А-ЯЁЇІЄҐ]", input)
```

An apostrophe is also considered a Ukrainan letter, no idea if you want to include it into the pattern.

Comment: Can I use this for Ukrainian AND Russian at the same time? For mixed input?

Comment: [Ukranian letter regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798522/regular-expression-not-working-for-at-least-one-european-character/30798598#30798598) is `[а-щА-ЩЬьЮюЯяЇїІіЄєҐґ]`. So, you need to add `ЇІЄҐ` to the character class. Not sure what you want to do with `'` though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ukrainian, so I'm not sure what `'` is for and so far have chosen to delete it from the input string until I know. But what if I realize later on I need it, how do I add it to the regex? `ЇІЄҐ'` ?

Comment: Yeah, something like `r"(?i)[А-ЯЁЇІЄҐ'’]"`. See [Ukrainian alphabet at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet#Alphabet).