# JavaScript surname validation with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write validation for surname with polish letters.

I wrote something like this:

```
"^[A-Z][\u0000-\u007F\u0100-\u017F]+([ |-][A-Z][\u0000-\u007F\u0100-\u017F])*$"
```

where:

- `[A-Z]`:  the first letter must be capital
- `[\u0000-\u007F\u0100-\u017F]+`: other letters
- `([ |-][A-Z][\u0000-\u007F\u0100-\u017F])*`: space for optional second part of surname with a `"-"` or space

Everything is fine, but when I type for example:

```
"Matt...;'"
```

I still have a match. How can I "cut" symbols like dots `.` and quotation marks?

Comment: For what exact purpose, I wonder? What kind of service on the web would have to put such specific importance on what a persons name is?

Comment: `\u0000-\u007F` is all of ASCII, not just letters.

Comment: `[ |-]` is `-` or space or `|`, not just `-` or space.

Comment: Your regex doesn't accept `Łukasiewicz`.

Comment: Hej, try [`^[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+(?:[\s-][A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+){1,2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/EPaz7I/3), it will match `Jan Maria Rokita` and `Jan Kowalski`, `Joanna Kluzik-Rostkowska` and even `Edward Ącki`. See [my answer with Polish (and other) letter ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/3832970).

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. Your regex work great.

Comment: @FilipW I posted a better answer below. Please consider accepting/upvoting. If you find fault with the solution below, please consider dropping a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may use

```
^[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+(?:\s[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+)?\s[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+(?:-[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nq4Q8N/1).

It is based on all [Polish alphabet letters regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/3832970) (that excludes `V`/`v`, `Q`/`q` and `X`/`x` from the ASCII letter range) and will match names that:

- Matches a first name
- Then may match an optional second first name (after a whitespace)
- A surname
- An optional surname part after a hyphen.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+` - an uppercase Polish letter and 1+ lowercase ones
- `(?:\s[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of a whitespace and then an uppercase Polish letter and 1+ lowercase ones
- `\s` - a single whitespace char
- `[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+` - an uppercase Polish letter and 1+ lowercase ones
- `(?:-[A-PR-UWY-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-pr-uwy-ząćęłńóśźż]+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of a hyphen and then an uppercase Polish letter and 1+ lowercase ones
- `$` - end of string.

If you plan to support `x`, `q` and `v` in the names, replace `a-pr-uwy-z` with `a-z` and `A-PR-UWY-Z` with `A-Z`.