# How can I use RegEx to remove certain words in from string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need to clean some cells and only keep important words to generate a search index.

Eg. "How to make an account recovery request" would be trimmed to "Make Account Recovery Request" because "How, To, An" would be in a list of words to be filtered out.

The other complexity is that it will also be in French and Spanish, which means that I have to deal with part-word like d'.

So far I've been trying to use a function but it doesn't work with part-word (d') and if "de" and "des" are listed in the same cell, it will remove DE from DES and then only keep the lonely S because DES is not recognized anymore:

```
Function ClearWords(s As String, rWords As Range) As String
Static RX As Object

If RX Is Nothing Then
    Set RX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RX.Global = True
    RX.IgnoreCase = True
End If

RX.Pattern = "\b" & Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(rWords), "|"), ".", "\.") & "\b"

ClearWords = Application.Trim(RX.Replace(s, ""))
End Function
```

Comment: Have you considered searching for "account", "recovery" and "request" turning up together ie and() ?

Comment: I have, but it will be user generated and expand over time. It would be far easier to filter out common words.

Comment: Ok, so how about removing any word of 3 letters or less?

Comment: I think that your request to handle foreign languages is far too broad for this question. For that, you're most likely going to need some way of sniffing the language from the input to determine *which* set of rule(s) to apply (it's probably not a good idea to send English text to French replacement, or vice versa etc.)  When you get to that point, I think that should be a separate question, not part of this one.

Comment: Would not work as I might need to delete word from variable length.

Comment: It would partially work. You can use multiple rules to process the input. I don't think Solar Mike suggests that should be your *only* rule.

Comment: Please also consider adding a [mcve] (self-contained example, that doesn't rely on your worksheet -- It should be easy for you to mock a simply string array or delimited list that represents your `rWords` transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to support English, French, and other European languages you may leverage  the regex I posted at [Regular expression not working for at least one European character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/3832970)
, `(?![×÷])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]`. This is a pattern that is supposed to match all the alphabetic chars you need to support. Since you are going to use it in VBA, it makes sense to replace literal extended letters with `\uXXXX` entities, and convert it to a single character class, `[A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF]` (`[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]` with literal chars).

Now, you need to build the custom boundaries. The initial boundary is either start of the string, `^`, or any char other than the letters above (and possibly digits, and `_`, if you want to fully emulate `\b`). Since you want to replace, you need to put these two patterns into a `(^|[^A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF])` *capturing group* and use `$1` in the replacement pattern to restore the value in order not to lose it. The trailing boundary is any char other than the letters above (or digits / `_`) and end of the string. Since VBA regex supports lookaheads, we may just use a *negative lookahead*, `(?![A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF])`.

Putting it together:

```
RX.Pattern = "(^|[^A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF])(?:" & Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(rWords), "|"), ".", "\.") & ")(?![A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF])"
ClearWords = Application.Trim(RX.Replace(s, "$1"))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WJsy53/1).

To also remove spaces before, replace `"(^|[^A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF])(?:"` with `(?:\s+|(^|[^A-Za-z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF]))(?:`. See [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/NzWwZx/1).

Bonus: you seem to need to escape the words to use them in a regex:

```
Dim regExEscape As New RegExp
With regExEscape
    .pattern = "[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
End With
```

Just make sure you process all words you have instead of `Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(rWords), "|"), ".", "\.")`.