# Regular Expression, RegEx, for validation of complex string in php

Tags: php, regex

Hey I am trying to get a php RegEx for a string with following valid characters:

Any [a-zA-Z]* (a-Z) strings are allowed, and than numbers with the format: /xxx, where xxx stands for numbers as follows: 000-032 and 035 and 092. 
And these strings and \xxx sequences can be concatenated in any way, as many times as we want, fore example:

"STring\032with\032a\032\032\backslash\032\092and\010a\035newLine"

What I got so far is this RegEx: [[a-z]*\\0([0-2][0-9]|3[0-2]|35|92)]*

But it seems to only recognize strings with a 'string part' concatonated with a 'backslash part' : "exampleString\032" and nothething afterwards

PLUS can I somehow make a REGEX where the string characters can be of a specific alphabet? Like lets say German or Czech?

Comment: You are looking for [`|` alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). And no, a regex can't reasonably specify a language.

Comment: I tried to come up with some language alphabet regexps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/3832970), but the list is not exhaustive. Also, borrowings that may keep original spellings might fail to match when using these regexps.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my OCD is going insane. You list the swedish letters in the wrong order. `åäöÅÄÖ` please.... :-) and the Norwegian is the same.

Comment: @Andreas No idea, I think the order was just the order from Wikipedia.

Comment: It would help if you actually showed an example string with your data, and then show another string containing the match pulled from your example string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will do the trick :

```
^((([a-zA-Z])\\?)*(((0[0-2][0-9])|(03[0-2])|(035)|(092))\\?)*)+$
```

[Successfully tested here.](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I just have one question, it is working just fine on regex101, but it does not seem to work in my php code using preg_match.

Comment: preg_match('/((([a-zA-Z])\\?)*(((0[0-2][0-9])|(03[0-2])|(035)|(092))\\?)*)+/', $your_string);