# Regular expression excluding a specific optional suffix in

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm willing to match words based on [Ssinn] in the middle of a phrase :

> Sinn, Sinne, Sinnes, sinnbelebte, sinnbelebten, sinnbelebter, sinnerfüllenden, sinnerfüllendem, Sinnesgehalt, sinngebenden, Sinnesbestände, Sinnlosigkeit, Sinnesmodifikation, sinnleeren Zeichen, sinnverleihende Akte, Widersinn, widersinnigen Ausdruck

But to exclude the following ones starting with -lich suffix

> Sinnlichkeit

For example in the following phrase, **sinngebenden** should match but **not sinnliche**

> Also im sinngebenden Aktcharakter, der ein ganz anderer ist, je nachdem das Interesse auf das sinnliche Zeichen oder auf das mittels des Zeichens vorstellig gemachte (wenn auch durch keinerlei Phantasievorstellung verbildlichte) Objekt gerichtet ist, liegt die Bedeutung

So far I had come-up with

> (?:\S+)?(?:[Ss]inn)(?:\S+)?

But in order to exclude the *lich* suffix, I tried

> (?:\S+)?(?:[Ss]inn)((?!lich)(?:\S+))?

which does not seem to work with Javascript RegEx...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The suggested regex is

```
\b[Ss]inn(?!lich)[a-z]*\b
```

Of course, if you want to allow other characters, such as the hyphen or letters from the German alphabet such as `ä`, `ö` and `ü`, in the rest of the word, just add them to the character set `[a-z]` or alter it accordingly.

Note that if you are using a regex implementation that does not consider non-ASCII letters to be word characters, then the use of the word boundary assertions `\b` would be unreliable.

An alternative strategy could be to use a negative lookbehind to assert that there isn't a character in the German alphabet preceding the `[Ss]inn`, and to omit the trailing `\b`. For example:

```
(?<![a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ])[Ss]inn(?!lich)[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ]*
```

That would still match the `Sinn` in `Sinn4U`, but that probably isn't an issue and could be disallowed by a lookahead if necessary.

It is not clear why you were beginning your regex with `(?:\S+)?`, as that is equivalent to `\S*`, and means match zero or more non-whitespace characters.

Comment: It is very clear why `\S+` was used: to match German words fully. Your regex does not match them correctly, see this proof: https://regex101.com/r/6Gukcg/1

Comment: @RyszardCzech As I mention in my answer, "if you want to allow other characters... just add them to the group [a-z]". It is trivial for the OP to add `ü` etc. to the group or use `\S` instead. The characters that may need to be added would depend on the the age of the text and the particular German alphabet used. You seem to misunderstand my last sentence: I was questioning the use of `(?:\S+)?` at the start of the regex, not the use of `\S+` per se.

Comment: No, it is fr from trivial, your "if you want to allow other characters... just add them to the group [a-z]" is not going to work because of word boundaries that do not work with non-ASCII letters. The problem is far more complex than you are trying to convince readers.

Comment: @RyszardCzech Yes, if that was an issue the `\b` would have to be removed. What is considered a word character, and therefore word boundary, differs across regex implementations. Thank you for pointing out that the regex would not match certain characters in the German alphabet and the possible word boundary issue. I have expanded the answer accordingly.

Comment: You can't simply remove word boundaries in regular expressions that must match whole words. This is no longer in line with the original OP intention, and is likely to cause  unwelcome matches (words that contain numbers or underscores at the end, for example)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not easy to solve as you need full regex Unicode support. With JavaScript environments that are not ECMAScript 2018+ compatible, you will need to use some work-arounds, that might fail in some edge cases.

Here are two short regexps, the first one requires ECMAScript 2018+ support, the second one does not:

```js
/\b[Ss]inn(?!lich)\p{L}*/gu
/\b[Ss]inn(?!lich)[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]*/g
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/UNA5jI/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/UNA5jI/4/).

Note the `[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]` character class matches any letter from a German alphabet + ASCII letters, see [Regular expression not working for at least one European character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/3832970).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[Ss]inn` - `S` or `s` and `inn`
- `(?!lich)` - not `lich` allowed immediately to the right
- `\p{L}*` - zero or more Unicode letters
- `[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]*` - zero or more ASCII or German letters.

**However**, if the word boundary `\b` does not help, and you get matches that start from a middle of the word, you can only emulate the Unicode word boundary by changing `(?:(?<=^|\W)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W|$))` into

```js
const w = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const nw = String.raw`[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const uwb = String.raw`(?:(?<=${nw}|^)(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=${nw}|$))`;

const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`${uwb}[Ss]inn(?!lich)\p{Alphabetic}*`, 'gu');
```

And this requires ECMAScript 2018+ compliant `RegExp`.
See the following JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = 'Also im sinngebenden Aktcharakter, der ein ganz anderer ist, je nachdem das Interesse auf das sinnliche Zeichen oder auf das mittels des Zeichens vorstellig gemachte (wenn auch durch keinerlei Phantasievorstellung verbildlichte) Objekt gerichtet ist, liegt die Bedeutung';
const w = String.raw`[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const nw = String.raw`[^\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`;
const uwb = String.raw`(?:(?<=${nw}|^)(?=${w})|(?<=${w})(?=${nw}|$))`;

const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`${uwb}[Ss]inn(?!lich)\p{Alphabetic}*`, 'gu');

console.log(text.match(regex));
```