# REGEX: How to allow exclusive latin characters (like accents)?

Tags: javascript, regex

So if you ever need a regular expression to verify whether a name has been inputted correctly for instance, and you want it to allow only Latin characters and accents, ***here's a solution:***

`\^([A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-Ý]){2,20}$\`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But I owe you an explanation as to why we have `À-ÖØ-Ý` and not just `À-Ý`

**Foremost, this explanation what made exclusively for beginners:**

When you use [A-Z], you capture any ASCII character between A and Z : you capture a **range**.

If you look at the Unicode U0000 character map/ASCII Table (see below), you'll notice that it matches exactly all uppercase.

[image: Screenshot of an ASCII Table, Unicode U0000]

In the same way, you can capture the 4 last lines of the Unicode U0080:
[image: Screenshot of an ASCII Table, Unicode U0080]

Though, you may realize that the multiplication (×) and division (÷) symbols are within that range.

Which is a problem because users (especially mobile users) could bypass the "only Latin letters" rule.

So to fix this issue we need to create 2 range of characters excluding these 2 characters.

Hence, why the `À-ÖØ-Ý`for uppercase letters with accents and `à-öø-ÿ` for lowercase letters with accents.

I hope this will be useful to some people!

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask them!

Sources:

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_des_caract%C3%A8res_Unicode/U0080

Comment: Thanks! I was using `A-Za-zŽžÀ-ÿ`, I'll replace it with `A-Za-zŽžÀ-ÖØ-Ýà-öø-ÿ`!

Comment: Or as written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798598/1052033 you can use `(?![×÷])[A-Za-zÀ-ÿ]`

Comment: The character class [A-Za-zÀ-ÿ] provided by @Antoine  is the cleanest, clearest and most useful.